# How do I make iframe scroll to an anchor in parent content on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, iframe, scroll, anchor

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content='15' http-equiv='refresh'>
<title>iframe bug on iOS</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<iframe src="https://tubestatus.net/departures/central/SFD?m#07514e542a078b1e80375762de74d4ab" 
height="474" width="352" Scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</p>
<p>Open this HTML on any browser other than iOS, and the top of the content 
from the parent page, shown in the iframe, is Westbound Platform 3, which is 
the desired behaviour I want.  Open this HTML on iOS, you see the top of the 
parent webpage (scroll doesn't happen / is broken).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As rendered from e.g. Chrome:

[image: Image of Chrome rendering - desired behaviour]

As rendered by browsers on iOS (even macOS Safari is unaffected, just an iOS issue):

[image: Image of iOS rendering - broken behaviour]

I understand there may be a bug in iOS rendering engine that I may need to work around by wrapping the iframe in a div for example, but then how do I get the div wrapped around the iframe to look into the material from the parent website in the iframe, and find the anchor #07514e542a078b1e80375762de74d4ab (a GUID which maps 1:1 with this Westbound platform 3), and scroll down to the correct point on the page, on any iOS device?

The parent website I am targeting with my iframe is not operated by me, I cannot change anything over there - I just want to embed the Westbound trains only, from the parent page, on a status page I host.

Comment: I have also tried changing scrolling=“no” to scrolling=“yes” and adding style=“-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;” to iframe element to “unstick” it on iOS without success, so really hoping someone can show me a code snippet to point me in the right direction how to use a div to scroll a whole iframe inside it down to the anchor.  The Westbound trains are below Eastbound trains whose number changes, and moves the Westbound trains on the page so scroll location needs to be calculated from anchor, not just fixed scroll position.

Comment: Is there a javascript way of detecting iOS and then putting back in the scroll to anchor behaviour on the iframe to replace the missing/broken functionality there? That would be a good solution for me, but I couldn’t find any example code with a couple hours of googling.